# bash IFS split string into array

Tags: arrays, bash, ifs

I have the following line `filename:231:blahblah` that I want to split into an array using `:` as the delimiter

The is the code that I have

```
echo "Text read from file: $line"
IFS=':' read -a FILENAME <<< $line
echo "filename: ${FILENAME[0]}"
```

actual output is

```
Text read from file: filename:231:blahblah 
filename: filename 231 blahblah
```

The output I want is

```
Text read from file: filename:231:blahblah 
filename: filename
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Quote `$line` when reading into array => `read -a FILENAME <<< "$line"`

Comment: You aren't doing anything wrong. There is a bug in `bash`, fixed in version 4.3, that causes the `IFS` setting to be incorrectly mixed with the parameter expansion in the here string.

Comment: @chatraed When `bash` works correctly, the quotes aren't necessary. A single parameter expansion doesn't undergo word-splitting when it is the argument of the here-string operator.

Comment: @chepner: thanks, you always provide crystal clear explanations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Solution 1:*

```
line="filename:231:blahblah"
IFS=':'
FILENAME=($line)
echo "filename: ${FILENAME[0]}"
```

*Solution 2 (derived from your try):*

```
line="filename:231:blahblah"
IFS=':' read -a FILENAME <<< "$line"
echo "filename: ${FILENAME[0]}"
```

Run result:

```
filename: filename
```